# Access docker mysql in wsl from windows

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have mysql database in docker in WSL. I would like to access it from my windows host. However the `172.x.x.x` IP is not accessible from the host. How would I achieve that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1143853

Comment: Where are you running docker? Have you installed it yourself in your linux distro, or are you using the docker for windows integration?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this as I see:

1. When launching the MySQL image, use the `--network` switch to include your host's IP range OR
2. Edit `mysql.cnf` config file to allow either ALL networks (0.0.0.0) or only your host's network (172.xx.xx.xx) into MySQL

Answer (score -1):

In Windows, you have to start the Docker Engine application. It will acts as a proxy towards containers started inside the WSL. Then, in the Settings of DE, enable the WSL Intergration.